# Facebook C# SDK friend invitation

Tags: c#, facebook, silverlight, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a problem with inviting friends to my application. I tried 
with Stack Overflow question *[Application generated apprequests failing in Silverlight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654379)*, but it works only when the user already has that application. If not, I get an exception:

> (OAuthException) (#200) All users in param ids must have accepted TOS.

So I want to inivite a friend directly through the C# SDK in Silverlight application by user ID, not Facebook dialog box. Is it possible to do this? I'm googling for two days...

Answer (score 1):

For requests without a dialog box, your app can only re-invite user ids of people who already use the app, in an attempt to get the user to re-engage with the app.  See the **app to user section** of https://developers.facebook.com/docs/requests/

> App to User Requests can be used to re-engage a user in your app and
>   can only be sent to users that have installed the app. For example,
>   notifying a user that something has changed since their last visit,
>   "10 of your friends are now online".
>
> App to User Request are sent via the Graph API, for more information
>   see the apprequests docs. App to User Requests are only available for
>   Canvas apps, not websites, as accepting a request will direct the user
>   to the Canvas Page URL of the app that sent the Request.

As you can see from the error message you received, that it is not permissible to do this to ids that have 1) never authorized your app or 2) someone who authorized your app, and then subsequently removed the app.

Happy Coding.

Comment: So i think its facebook feature to block spamers;) And I have another question, how to display invitation box via Silverlight ? I want to display invitation dialog for one user , but i have no idea how to do it in silverlight.

Comment: Please ask your additional question as a new question.  Here on StackoverFlow we like one question one answer.  :)  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to request a dialog from facebook to invite non-app users.
Do have a look at my answer here.

[Is facebook user to user request possible with W8/WP8 c# sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21067358/is-facebook-user-to-user-request-possible-with-w8-wp8-c-sharp-sdk)